# Is there a parallel SSH client with grid output similar to multitail

Tags: ssh, terminal

I've used multitail to monitor multiple log files on a single machine and displaying them in a "grid view" (2x3 or something similar).

I was wondering if there is any such tool for SSH? Anything that allows me to open a single terminal window but split that up into an NxM grid and run different sessions in each?

Changing window managers is not an option. I need this inside the same terminal window.

Comment: Take a look at `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

To work on multiple servers at once, you can use screen or tmux. To manage them all in lockstep, there's capistrano or clusterssh.

To start screen with a bunch of predetermined sessions in a predetermined grid, add commands to your .screenrc file, for example:

```
# split window horizontally:
split
# split top segment vertically:
split -v
screen -t 'host1' 0 ssh host1
# skip to next window:
focus
screen -t 'host2' 0 ssh host2
# skip to next window:
focus
# split bottom segment vertically:
split -v
screen -t 'host3' 0 ssh host3
# skip to next window:
focus
screen -t 'host4' 0 ssh host4
```

This is cumbersome, but it should work.  See `man screen` for details.  tmux may make this easier - I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't need to manage them in lockstep so that's fine. I haven't been able to figure out how to use screen to display a grid though... I can split it either horizontally or vertically but I would like to start screen up with M*N many sessions in an MxN grid.

Comment: Post edited to show one way to do that.

Comment: Thanks... as you point out, screen is quite cumbersome. Even if there is an "easy" way to start the grid, switching between them is really annoying with the "double stroke keyboard shortcuts".

There are a few shells that seem to offer this. Alas, my terminal emulator of choice (konsole) only allows me to split either horizontally or vertically. A promising one is Terminator but I haven't been able to install that on my ubuntu for some reason.

The search will go on.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to set up Terminator which is pretty much exactly what I needed. It allows me to split the window arbitrarily and have different shell sessions running in each.

It supports defining your custom layouts and then you can start it up and specify what layout to use. The layout determines the layout of the terminal windows and also allows you to specify a custom command to run within each session.